# tsql selecting record based upon date and null

Tags: t-sql, date, select

I have a table:

```
ID as int, ParentId as int, FreeFromTerxt as varchar(max), ActiveUntil as DateTime
```

As an example, within this table I have two records.

```
1, 100, 'Some text', '2015-11-30 12:10:09.0000000'
2, 100, 'New  text', null
```

What I am trying to do is get the current active record, which in the case above would by record 1. To do that I just select with the following criteria:

```
ActiveUntil > GETDATE()
```

This works great, but if I change the first date to 2015-10-30, I need to get the null record as this record will take precedence.

So I changed the code to be:

```
((ActiveUntil is NULL) OR (ActiveUntil > GETDATE()))
```

But this does not work.

Comment: You want to take the null record as fallback record if there is none per `ParentID` which `ActiveUntil` is in the future? You want only one per `ParentId` or all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example with `union`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( d DATETIME )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( NULL ),
        ( '2015-11-30' )

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM    ( SELECT    * , 1 AS ordering
          FROM      @t
          WHERE     d > GETDATE()
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    * , 2 AS ordering
          FROM      @t
          WHERE     d IS NULL
        ) t
ORDER BY ordering, d
```

For `2015-11-30` it returns `2015-11-30`. For `2015-10-30` it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
((ActiveUntil is NULL) OR (CONVERT(char(10), ActiveUntil  ,126)) > GETDATE())
```

Refer MSDN for [Cast and Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx). The format specifier 126 is for YYYY-MM-DD. Or you can use CAST

```
((ActiveUntil is NULL) OR (CAST(ActiveUntil as Date) > GETDATE())
```

Comment: You shoud cast ActiveUntil  not getdate. And better cast to date, because you are casting to varchar and then to date again

Comment: The problem with this is when having `2015-11-30` in table it will return 2 rows.